# How to get number of how much i have colums(data) in my SQL DataBase android app)

Tags: android, sqlite

I have dtabase

```
public DataAdapter(Context context){
    helper = new DataHelper(context);
}
public long insertData(String worB1, String worB2)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(helper.WORB1, worB1);
    contentValues.put(helper.WORB2, worB2);
    long id=db.insert(helper.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    return id;
}
public String getAllData()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] colums = {DataHelper.UID, DataHelper.WORB1, DataHelper.WORB2};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(DataHelper.TABLE_NAME, colums, null, null, null, null, null);
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (cursor.getWantsAllOnMoveCalls())
    {
        int cid = cursor.getInt(0);
        String name = cursor.getString(1);
        String pass = cursor.getString(2);
        buffer.append(cid+ " "+name+ " "+pass+"\n");
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}
public String FindById(int id)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] colums = {DataHelper.WORB1, DataHelper.WORB2};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(DataHelper.TABLE_NAME, colums, DataHelper.UID + "='" + id + "'", null, null, null, null);
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        int index0 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DataHelper.WORB1);
        int index1 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DataHelper.WORB2);
        String personName = cursor.getString(index0);
        String pass = cursor.getString(index1);
        buffer.append(personName + " "+ pass + "\n");
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}
class DataHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "NekData";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "NekTable";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String UID = "_id";
    private static final String WORB1 = "worb1";
    private static final String WORB2 = "worb2";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + WORB1 + " VARCHAR(255), " + WORB2 + " VARCHAR(255));";
    private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;
    private final Context context;
    public DataHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
            Message.message(context, "All OK");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Message.message(context, "" + e);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

and i wanna create function to get number of how much i have colums (id) in my database.
How to do it ?

for example i am added first colume == neka, pass ; ecound colume == neka2, pass2 and when i run it function it get me numer "2" becouse i have two colums

Answer (score 0):

I dont sure what you are actually asking here, but if youre asking for columns count its a constant which you can obtain by counting the columns (you actually defuned by yourself) in SqLiteDbHelper class.

If you are wish to get something else, please clearfy your question, its very hard to understand.

Comment: i wanna get number of how much i added data

Comment: So get all the data and count the rows

Comment: How to count the rows

Comment: Sql count statment, or just iterate the cursor for all the rows. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp